# Can rsyslogd write to more than one named pipe

Tags: rsyslog, fifo

If I have the following two lines in the rsyslogd.conf

```
*.* |/var/run/rsyslog/pipe1
*.* |/var/run/rsyslog/pipe2
```

Will all messages be sent to both pipes? I have two programs that want to inspect lines written to syslog, for different purposes. One program I wrote and one I didn't, hence the two named pipes.

Comment: What did experiments determined?

Comment: It doesn't work. It only writes to the second pipe.